# Static vs dynamic type

Tags: swift, reflection

In Swift we can determine type of variable by `type(of:)` and `Mirror(reflecting:).subjectType`.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror/1539349-subjecttype) about `Mirror.subjectType` says:

> The static type of the subject being reflected.
>
> This type may differ from the subject’s dynamic type when self is the superclassMirror of another mirror.

I did not find docs for `type(of:)` but the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0096-dynamictype.md) says that it's replacement for `.dynamicType` property.

So we have dynamic and static types. What the difference between them and in what circumstances does it show up?

**P.S.**
I'm asking because I'm having strange issue. This code:

```
protocol A: class {
}

class B: A {
}

let b = B()

class C<T> {
    func test(value: T) {
        print("\(type(of: value))")
        print("\(Mirror(reflecting: value).subjectType)")
    }
}

func test(a: A) {
    print("\(type(of: a))")
    print("\(Mirror(reflecting: a).subjectType)")
}

C<A>().test(value: b)
test(a: b)
```

when running on iPhone from Xcode using Debug configuration gives output:

```
B
B
B
B
```

and running using Release configuration (switch to it under `Product -> Scheme -> Edit -> Build Configuration -> Release`) gives:

```
A
B
B
B
```

which seams to be a bug in Swift compiler.

**UPDATE** I opened [JIRA ticket](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3304).

Comment: In some quick tests with NSObject subclasses, pure Swift classes, and structs, I did not see any differences between the types returned from `type(of:)` and `Mirror(reflecting:).subjectType`.  If you believe you have encountered a compiler bug, I recommend opening a JIRA ticket on http://bugs.swift.org.

Comment: @JAL Done. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3304) should be [fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6395) in master now and in next (after 3.0.2) Swift version soon.

Thanks to [Joe Groff](https://github.com/jckarter).